# Jquery ajax call and charset windows-1252

Tags: php, jquery, encoding, windows-1252

Dear stackoveflow, I have this problem. I'm working with an old version of mssql (2000) that has all the tables encoded in windows 1252 (and that's it). I can write and read succesfully with php using this line:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252'); ?>
```

If I make a normal post everything works as expected, If I do it ajax style I write messed characters in the table. I've also tried this:

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=windows-1252",
```

With no luck. Can anybody help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible to change the character set for incoming data from the Ajax request in Javascript somehow, butt IIRC, it's complex and is likely to have cross browser issues.

If you are querying a PHP script, the easiest way woudl be to convert the data to UTF-8 there:

```
$data = "Höllo, thüs üs windows-1252 encoded data";

$data_utf8 = iconv("windows-1252", "utf-8", $data);

echo $data;
```

Comment: can I send ajax data to db as windows-1252 encoded form data this way?

Comment: @xy_ no, this converts the data into UTF-8 which is the default method for Ajax transmissions

Comment: Well than, is there a way of sending ajax data as windows-1252 encoded?

Comment: @xy_ there might be, but I've never figured out how it's being done exactly. What do you need it for?

Comment: Actually it is about following topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640363/stuck-at-jquery-ajax-db-encoding-for-iso-8859-9-charset