# Stuck at Jquery Ajax Db Encoding for ISO-8859-9 Charset

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, asp-classic

I am trying to pass data to db via my Jquery application. I have serious problems with encoding.

Current page encoding is iso-8859-9. I've made my ajax page encoding to iso-8859-9 and passing .ajax data with `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-9"`

It stores `İZİN` value as `Ä°ZÄ°N` with every single trying.

Is it work if I create a PHP page and set encoding with headers?

PS: I am processing data on an HTML page. Processor page is an ASP page and using MsSQL db I guess. I don't have access to processor page or db. Just entering data via form post.

**İZİN** word and some other similar words are using for sql query at some other pages on WHERE clauses. So I cannot convert characters into HTML codes. I have to use İ as İ.

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: You may be "passing ajax data with contentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-9" but are you actually ensuring it is encoded as ISO-8859-9.  Sounds to me like you are still sending UTF-8 encoding despite the claim in your content type otherwise.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones how can I be sure? I set it to ISO-8859-9 both in meta header and ajax query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` does not have a charset. It's simply ASCII characters. Specifying charset there will do nothing.

jQuery will normally urlencode your data as [is specified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Current_standard):

1. Encode to UTF-8
2. Percent-encode

So:

```
$.post( "test.php", {data: 'İZİN'}); //Shorthand for $.ajax
```

Actually posts this to server:

```
data=%C4%B0Z%C4%B0N
```

When you access `$_POST['data']` with php, they have been turned into bytes (`0xC4B05AC4B04E`), so echoing them will give you malformed data:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9");
echo $_POST['data'];
// Ä°ZÄ°N
```

You can test this is true with:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9");
echo "\xC4\xB0\x5A\xC4\xB0\x4E";
// Ä°ZÄ°N
```

In PHP you need convert it to ISO-8859-9 as soon as you receive it:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9");
$data =  "\xC4\xB0\x5A\xC4\xB0\x4E"; //$_POST['data'];
$proper = mb_convert_encoding( $data, "ISO-8859-9", "UTF-8" );
echo $proper;
//İZİN
```

Note that it's just much easier to use UTF-8 everywhere because it's pretty much the best encoding and the web loves it. If you use any other encoding then you will have to be on your toes all the time.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I always use UTF-8 with my applications but this is an app developed before and I don't have access neither script nor db. So I have to find a way to do it with those charsets. If it is possible.

Comment: I'm using ASP Classic. If I set the HTML page to UTF-8 encoding, when I post (using a standard HTML Form element), the data received at server-side replaces accented characters with ?. But when I do a GET the characters are displayed properly. Using IE 11 in Compatibility Mode.